# Can't refresh view after changing published variable

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, mobile

I have three files: ContentView (main file), HomeView, ConfigView

I wish I could change one string that is located in HomeView by pressing a button in ConfigView, but I can't do it.

Edit: I realized the problem is because I'm storing objects inside the `DadosTimes` class. I tried to store a simple string and it worked. How can I make it work even using an object?

## ContentView file:

```swift
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    func inExpandingRectangle() -> some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.clear)
            self
        }
    }
}

//Here i have a declaration for a custom button

class Equipe {
    var nome: String
    var pontos: Int
    var vitorias: Int
    
    init(nome: String) {
        self.nome = nome
        self.pontos = 0
        self.vitorias = 0
    }
    
    func addPontos(_qtd: Int){
        self.pontos += _qtd
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var InfoJogo: DadosTimes
    var body: some View {
        TabView{
            HomeView()
                .tabItem({
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                    Text("Placar")
                })
            
            ConfigView()
                .tabItem({
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                    Text("Configurações")
                })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

class DadosTimes: ObservableObject{
    @Published var time1 = Equipe(nome: "Nós")
    @Published var time2 = Equipe(nome: "Eles")
}
```

## HomeView file:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var InfoJogo: DadosTimes
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color("FundoVerde")
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                HStack{
                    VStack(spacing: 0){
                        TextField("", text: $InfoJogo.time1.nome)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            .font(.system(size: 50))
                        Text(String(InfoJogo.time1.pontos))
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            .font(.system(size: 85))
                        Text(String(InfoJogo.time1.vitorias) + " Vitórias")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.darkGray))
                            .font(.system(size: 17))
                        
                        BotaoPrimario(title: "+", size: 50, action: {
                            InfoJogo.time1.addPontos(_qtd: 1)
                            verificaGanhador()
                        })
                    }
                    .inExpandingRectangle()
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    VStack(spacing: 0){
                        Text(InfoJogo.time2.nome)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            .font(.system(size: 50))
                        Text(String(InfoJogo.time2.pontos))
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            .font(.system(size: 85))
                        Text(String(InfoJogo.time2.vitorias) + " Vitórias")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.darkGray))
                            .font(.system(size: 17))
                        
                        BotaoPrimario(title: "+", size: 50, action: {
                            InfoJogo.time2.addPontos(_qtd: 1)
                            verificaGanhador()
                        })
                    }
                    .inExpandingRectangle()
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 50)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                    .shadow(radius: 15)
                )
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

## ConfigView file

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ConfigView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var InfoJogo: DadosTimes
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color("FundoVerde")
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack{
                Button("Mudar Nome"){
                    InfoJogo.time1.nome = "oiii"
                }
                TextField("", text: $InfoJogo.time1.nome)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ConfigView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ConfigView()
    }
}
```

I have already logged in console the InfoJogo.time1.nome variable and it changes in the memory. It's not updating on the screen. What should I do? I've already looked for help everywhere but I couldn't find the solution.

Sorry if it's a basic question, but I've started learning swift yesterday ;)

Comment: Where do you unit DadosTimes and how do you pass it in?

Comment: DadosTimes is a variable I created for storing two teams' information. When I click a button on the screen, it increases the score of a team.

Comment: Reading some of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswiftui%5D+nested+published) will probably help. `@Published` will trigger an update when the published value changes. In the case of a class, this means when the reference to the instance changes. It won't trigger an update just because a property of the class instance changes. In other words `InfoJogo.time1 = Equipe(nome:"blah")` would trigger an update because the value of `time1` changes but `InfoJogo.time1.pontos = 2` won't because the value of `time1` doesn't change.

Comment: Also, the style convention in Swift is that types (classes, structs etc) are named with a capital while variables are named with a lower case letter (ie it should be `infoJogos`)

Answer (score 0):

@Paulw11 provided a perfect description why the change doesn't trigger an update.

What you can do is trigger the update manually with `objectWillChange.send()`.

In your button action do:

```
BotaoPrimario(title: "+", size: 50, action: {
    infoJogo.objectWillChange.send() // here
    infoJogo.time2.addPontos(_qtd: 1)
    verificaGanhador()
})
```